# What is the reason that "Information management policy settings" link is showing under content type on some sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, content-type

I have created 2 identical sites of type communication sites, one of the sites have "Information management policy settings" link showing when i click on Content Type, as follow: -

[image]

While the other site does not, as follow:-

[image]

so, what determine the visibility of this link "Information management policy settings""? as in my case the 2 sites should have the same settings.

Thanks

And both sites have this site feature disabled "Library and Folder Based Retention":-

[image]

Comment: Is it the same content type? Are you using the content type gallery? (content type hub)

Comment: @CallumCrowley same content type in regards to the columns but i add it manually to each site separately I do not use any content type hub

Answer (score 0):

That link shows up for me when the Site Collection Feature 'Site Policy' is activated.

[image]

However deactivating the feature doesn't remove the link.

Comment: i have this feature disabled on both sites